# Bootstrap 3. What does having two column setting in an element mean?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting up to speed with Bootstrap's grid system but the following example confuses me. In the following there are two (2) column classes - `col-xs-5` and `col-lg-1` - for each `div` with class `form-group`

```
   <div class="container-fluid">

        <form role="form">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
                    <label>
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1 ">
                    <label>
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-normal" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Can someone explain why this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column class describes how many columns the element will take up at that designated breakpoint. For example:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1 ">...</div>
```

This element will take up 5 columns if the page is being rendered at the xs breakpoint (screen width of <768px) but will only take up one column at the lg breakpoint ( >1200px )

This lets you set the presentation of the same element at different screen widths.

Comment: Ah yes. Responsive design. Got it. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

For each row you have one column.

It's set to five columns wide for extra small to medium screen sizes with by "col-xs-5" and one column for large screen sizes with "col-lg-1". By default with bootstrap you can set four different layouts (extra small, small, medium and large) to suit different screen sizes.

If you make your browser window size smaller you will see how it effects it.

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for information on how the grid system works.

It's well worth reading though the documentation as it's very good. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/